# Brightway2 - Issue saving imported LCIA using SimaproLCIACSVImporter() method after fixing unlinked CFs

Tags: python, attributeerror, brightway

I want to import an LCIA-method which is costum made for the simapro CSV format.

I had issues fixing unlinked CFs, and followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800649/13602562) by @Cédric Furrer, which pracically almost worked out...
However, I cannot write the method afterwards. This error comes:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 my_method.write()

AttributeError: 'SimaProLCIACSVImporter' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I tried to inspect the impacted/impacting files, at no use.

I would expect .write() would work.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can ultimately save the LCIA-method ready for use in calculations?

**Specs:
**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.10
- Brightway2
- Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

The writing procedure for LCIA is different than that for LCI. You need to use [`write_methods()`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/main/bw2io/importers/base_lcia.py#L51) instead.